# How can I have the same color scale for two different graphics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of this sort

```
lat        long       val
41.69   -71.566389    0.25756813
41.69   -71.566389    0.325883146
42.86   -71.959722    0.897783941
42.86   -71.959722    0.621170816
42.37   -71.234167    0.224426988
41.84   -71.143333    0.048329645
```

The range of val is 0-1 in my full dataset. **I want to create two figures**, one which plots all the values from 0-1 and another which plots 0.5-1. **But both must be on the same color scale**.

I know I can subset them and create two figures. But I don't know how to make them in the same color scale.

Currently, I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
usamap <- map_data("state")
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(10, "Spectral")))
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=long,y=lat,color=val)) + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(size = 0.01)+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Range",colours = myPalette(10))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add the `limits` option to `scale_colour_gradientn`. For example:

```
#Simulate some example data
set.seed(1123)
df = data.frame(lon = rnorm(100), lat = rnorm(100), val = runif(100))

# Define colour palette
library(RColorBrewer)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(10, "Spectral")))

# Make plots
library(ggplot2)

## All points
ggplot(df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = val)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Range",colours = myPalette(10), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_bw() + xlim(-3, 3) + ylim(-3, 3)

## Subset
ggplot(subset(df, val >= 0.5), aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = val)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Range",colours = myPalette(10), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_bw() + xlim(-3, 3) + ylim(-3, 3)
```

Result:

[image: Example colour scale]